# PHP, jQuery & Chartist.Js: Display live data from database into Chart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chartist.js

I'm trying to make a chart where I can see the number of players of a server during 24h.
I want the chart to display from 00:00 to 11:59PM from 30 to 30 minutes. (00:30, 1:00, 1:30 etc.)

Code I'm using to send the array to the jQuery.

```
$json = array();
$stmt = $link->query("SELECT * FROM online WHERE time > $date");
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $row['time'] = date("H:i", $row['time']); //translate unix to human
  array_push($json, array('labels' => $row['time'],
    'series' => $row['players']
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array("json" => $json));
```

output:
[image]

This is the jQuery I'm using to display the chart

```
var url = "settings.php"
  var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url, 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
       }).responseText
     );

    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(resp);

    var data = {"labels":JSONObject.labels, "series":[JSONObject.series]};


  optionsPlayersOnline = {
    lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.cardinal({
      tension: 0
    }),
    low: 0,
    high: 50,
    chartPadding: {
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0
    },
  }

  var PlayersOnline = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, optionsPlayersOnline);
```

My problem is that I can't figure how to make the chart work and display.